# Setting up shared logins for web and system users

Tags: linux, passwords, central-authentication-service

I'm looking to create a web automation and administration area that users who have permissions to do system tasks can do them via them web, such as creating/editing users. I thought about making a system that syncs the system and web passwords, and when a user wants to do a specific task that requires root access, ask for their password for `sudo` and save the password in a session for a certain amount of time.

However, I realize this isn't a good practice, and if someone got access to session information they would be able to get the passwords for the users. So that led me to think about a Central Authentication Service for the system and the web users.

My questions are, is this possible, or has it been done? If so, how would I accomplish setting up this CAS system for web users and system users? How would I allow these CAS users to perform sudo actions? And, what other implications should I consider for this project?

Answer (score 0):

No need to sync the web server and system passwords, you can setup [mod-auth-external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) to delegate user authentication to PAM. However it will only authenticate the user on the webserver (using the systems credentials), not on the system (it's probably safer that way).

For web-based remote administration, you should probably look at [plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/), [cPanel](http://cpanel.net/) or [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) that do exactly that. Be extra careful if you want to reimplement this functionality in your own application: it's a security nightmare.

Comment: plesk and cPanel are commercial tools. I'm slapping myself for saying this but maybe Webmin would be 'better'.
But to clarify: Web Administration Tools are always a bad idea, because you can have a lot of security issues between the user and the system core (Browser, Network Communication, Webserver Implementation, Bugs in the Web Administration Software itself, bugs in the system that are only local exploitable but brought to the web with such tools, and so on). A lot of this tools caused a lot of systems being hijacked the past years and they are not easy to patch.

Comment: @noggerl that was to answer the "has it been done", and the answer is clearly yes. I'll add webmin to the list, and you're definitely right it's a major security risk, so I'll update my answer to  convey this as well.